# How do I listen for both read and write event with AnyEvent?

Tags: perl, event-handling

```
   $w = AnyEvent->io (
      fh   => <filehandle_or_fileno>,
      poll => <"r" or "w">,
      cb   => <callback>,
   );
```

[The manual](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MLEHMANN/AnyEvent-6.1/lib/AnyEvent.pm) seems to be saying it can only listen for either read or write event,

how do I listen for both of the events?

Answer (score 3):

Install two different watchers on same filehandle: r and w

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use AnyEvent;

open my $FH, '+>','test' or die $!;

my $w; $w = AnyEvent->io (
    fh   => $FH,
    poll => "w",
    cb   => sub { say "I can write!"; undef $w; },
);

my $r; $r = AnyEvent->io (
    fh   => $FH,
    poll => "r",
    cb   => sub { say "I can read!"; undef $r; },
);

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;
```

Comment: Will the first `cb` be overwriten?

Comment: Why don't you just try? I updated my answer with simple example. You may just adopt it to your needs. You can install as many watchers on object as you need.